# How to add a count == 0 to this?

Tags: php

I would like to add a `count == 0` which if it is the case, just outputs 'please contact us to find out the dates', but I can't seem to get it to work. Please can someone advise?

```
$count = 0;
$your_repeater = get_field('add_date');
if ($your_repeater) {
    while (have_rows('add_date')):
        the_row();
        $count++;
        $my_field = get_sub_field('course_date');

        if ($count == 0) {
            echo 'please contact us to find out dates';
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
        if ($count == 1) {
            $todays_date = date("Y-m-d");
            $today = strtotime($todays_date);
            $expiration_date = strtotime($my_field);
            if ($expiration_date > $today) {
                // echo $my_field .', ';
                $date12 = new DateTime($my_field);
                $date13 = new DateTime($todays_date);
                $diff = date_diff($date12, $date13);
                echo '<b>1. Starts on:</b> '.$my_field;
                echo '<div class="reddays"> in '.$diff->format("%R%a days.").'<a href="'.get_page_link(
                        '10'
                    ).'">    Contact us now</a></div>';
                //echo  '<a href="'.get_page_link('10') .'">Contact us to find out more</a>';
            } else {
                echo '';
            }
        }
        if ($count == 2) {
            $todays_date = date("Y-m-d");
            $today = strtotime($todays_date);
            $expiration_date = strtotime($my_field);
            if ($expiration_date > $today) {
                //echo $my_field .' ,';
                $date12 = new DateTime($my_field);
                $date13 = new DateTime($todays_date);
                $diff = date_diff($date12, $date13);
                echo '<b>2. Starts on:</b> '.$my_field;
                echo '<div class="reddays"> in '.$diff->format("%R%a days.").'<a href="'.get_page_link(
                        '10'
                    ).'">    Contact us now</a></div>';
                //echo '<img src="' .bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/themes/derbyskillbuild site/images/hourglass.png" />';
            } else {
                echo '';
            }
        }
        if ($count == 3) {
            $todays_date = date("Y-m-d");
            $today = strtotime($todays_date);
            $expiration_date = strtotime($my_field);
            if ($expiration_date > $today) {
                //echo $my_field .' ,';
                $date12 = new DateTime($my_field);
                $date13 = new DateTime($todays_date);
                $diff = date_diff($date12, $date13);
                echo '<b> 3. Starts on:</b> '.$my_field;
                echo '<div class="reddays"> in '.$diff->format("%R%a days.").'<a href="'.get_page_link(
                        '10'
                    ).'">    Contact us now</a></div>';
            } else {
                echo '';
            }
        }
        if ($count == 4) {
        }
        if ($count == 5) {
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    endwhile;
}
```

Comment: Place `$count++` above `endwhile`

Comment: Have you heard of the `switch` command?

Comment: add $count++;at the end of while loop

Comment: you increase the value of 'count' at the beginning of your while loop. In that very same while loop you do check for 0 value? This is simply not possible the way your code is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are checking the count way too soon in your code.

You start with a `$count = 0;`, but then in the while loop you first do `$count++`. So, at this point, the count is 1. Then a few lines later you check this:

```
        if ($count == 0) {
            echo 'please contact us to find out dates';
        }
```

This will **never** return true, since you just did a `$count++` from 0, so at this point it's always at least 1. It seems that this check should be outside of your while loop and you're currently closing the loop way too late.